# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS5 for IBAction

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have written a sample code for button click action in xcode 4.2 for iOS5.

Here is the code

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController


@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
-(IBAction)changed;
 @end
```

.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize button=_button;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}    

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(changed)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
-(IBAction)changed
{
    NSLog(@"clicked");

    }
    - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

But when I click the button. I am getting exception. how to solve this issue? the same is working in iOS 4.3

Comment: show the crash log and the statement where the app crashes..

Comment: Move your call to super to the top of your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: If I click button, its showing EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m

Comment: can you post the code of changed method?

Comment: I have posted. Please scroll down

Comment: Here is the link for that EXCEPTION
http://i.stack.imgur.com/mIcp7.png

Comment: @Bharath add exception breakpoint in the xcode

Answer (score 1):

first change this code into this one

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(changed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: @iNoob I hav put breakpoint also. But I am getting exception in main.m

My view is loading succesfully but I am not able to write actions. If I create button in my code using [UIButton alloc]initWithFrame..] the above code is working. But the same is not working if I use IBOutlet UIButton & connecting from xib file

Comment: I have run your code in my project and it's working fine... it must be some other problem... use break points to check this problem

Comment: @Bharath i hope you are clearing the code in which you created button programmatically, because BAD_ACCESS is usually got due to over-releasing of an object. As Inder mentioned this works fine, i just tried it on my machine as well.

Comment: @iNoob .. As afar as i see his code it seems he is using ARC and bad exe shouldn't be the case here.. I don't know why this simple code is not working on bharath's machine

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, didn't know he used ARC, but you're right this shouldn't cause any problem, `SIGABRT` is kind of understandable, but this i've no clue, will search on when do we get BAD_ACCESS with ARC.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore just stumbled on a similar question, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226596/bad-access-exception-using-xcode-4-2, he got it working when he disabled ARC, that's weird.

Comment: @Bharath though this won't actually answer your question but it helped the other guy solve his problem, i'm referring to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226596/bad-access-exception-using-xcode-4-2, he just disabled ARC and seem to work fine. But it bothers when you don't know a right solution though.  Even this question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109107/over-release-without-a-calltrace-using-arc-bad-acces-in-main

Comment: @iNoob thanks for the links, bharat.. either stop using ARC or upgarade your xcode

Comment: Guys, I created 4 sample projs ,enabling ARC & disabling ARC. Problem is not with ARC.

Comment: @Bharath you're getting bad access everytime?

Comment: @iNoob.. My problem got solved. its jus becoz in AppDelegate.m in viewDidLoad method I created FirstViewController obj and added to the window

FirstViewController *viewController=[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 "[self.window addSubView:viewController.view]"

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for my problem.

The main problem is that, if I create a view controller object locally (i.e., inside any method) and add it as subview then, when you invoke any `IBAction`, at that time it will raise an exception because, the memory for that viewController is getting deallocated automatically when declared locally.

Comment: This actually helped me track down my issue which was my view controller was getting garbage collected, I had to make it a strong variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess he needs to add data member for that button as well. I mean code should look like this.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{
  IBOutlet *UIButton *button;
}

@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
-(IBAction)changed;
 @end
```

and try replacing

```
@synthesize button = _button;
```

with

```
@synthesize button;
```

in your .m file.

Answer (score -1):

You have the wrong message signature for your `changed` action. It should be:

```
- (IBAction)changed:(id)sender
```

and in the addTarget line of code:

```
@selector(changed:)
```

PS: Why are you using `_button`? I don't think this is related to the problem, but you should be using `self.button` instead. Accessing instance variables directly should be avoided, especially in this case, where you are allowing the compiler to decide what name the variable should have.

PPS: As mentioned by @InderKumarRathore, you should also be calling `[super viewDidLoad]` before running your own code.

Comment: Hmmm.. I did all the changes u said. Same prob.
I changed my method name to -(IBAction)changed:(id)sender
and target to @selector(changed:),
_button to self.button. Even then. No change

Comment: I'm not sure then. I suspect the actual bug is somewhere else in your code. EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is often a memory management bug, do you have ARC enabled?

Comment: I already used      [super viewDidLoad] before my code. Same Porb

Comment: Not true about the message signature - it is perfectly ok to create and call selectors without the *sender* argument.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert.. Ya I enabled ARC